# I want to display date in table column sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, sql-server-2014

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Patient
  (
  PatientID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  LabControlID AS Cast(Right(Year(getDate()),4) as varchar(4)) +'-' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(PatientID AS VARCHAR(5)), 5),
  SequenceID AS "--Codes to display date--"
  ,First_Name varchar(50)
  ,Last_Name varchar(50)
  ,Age int
  ,Male bit
  ,Female bit
  ,
  )
```

I want to display Month and Day - 00000 and display like this in the example below.

```
SequenceID
----------   
Jan01-00001       
Jan01-00002
```

Please advise. Thanks :D

Comment: Why you want to do that? any use case? without knowing that, having computed column is the only option I can suggest, which is based on a date and identity column

Comment: How many patients per year? Will you be retired or elsewhere when `PatientID` hits 100,000?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should rethink your table structure:

1. Storing `Age` directly is tricky (will you update it every year). You should store `birthday` and calculate it.
2. Why 2 fields to indicate sex? `Male bit` and `Female bit`. Without check constraint you could get `male 1 and female 1`. Maybe just `isMale bit` will be sufficient or lookup table with more values if needed.
3. `LabControlID` uses `GETDATE` and it is time dependent. When year will change it will change too.

---

As for `SequenceId` you could use `FORMAT` and store `date` as normal column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl_Patient
(
  PatientID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  my_date DATE,
  SequenceID AS CONCAT(FORMAT(my_date,'MMMdd','en-US'),'-',FORMAT(PatientID,'0000#'))
  -- ...
);

INSERT INTO tbl_Patient(my_date)VALUES ('2016-01-01'),  ('2016-01-01');

SELECT * FROM tbl_Patient;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/NFME28805)**</kbd>

Output:

```sql
╔═══════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ PatientID ║       my_date       ║ SequenceID  ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║         1 ║ 01.01.2016 00:00:00 ║ Jan01-00001 ║
║         2 ║ 01.01.2016 00:00:00 ║ Jan01-00002 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: Hello Sir, how can I change into this one?

1. Storing Age directly is tricky (will you update it every year). You should store birthday and calculate it.


2. Why 2 fields to indicate sex? Male bit and Female bit. Without check constraint you could get male 1 and female 1. Maybe just isMale bit will be sufficient or lookup table with more values if needed.

Comment: @JaphetCompendioBatucan if this answer solves ur problem, then mark it as an answer. So, other people that have the same problem with you would know the answer. If you have another question, just edit ur question, or create another post. If you ask a question in a comment, its hard to be seen by others